# Allow flagging from within "New Answers to Questions More Than 30 Days Old"

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-abilities, new-answers

I frequently use the [New Answers to Questions More Than 30 Days Old](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) tool to find spam/NAA answers. A lot of them are often very obviously spam such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22079291/1069068), or very obviously not an answer, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22079122/1069068).

To flag these, I need to open them in a new tab, flag it, shut the tab and go back to looking through the list.

Could we please have the flag link added to the answers here as well? It would streamline the process and save me, and many other users who do this, a lot of time.

Comment: This would be very nice.  I got very used to keyboard shortcuts to go back when working through these.